# How to create fake call with default android screen incoming call?

Tags: android, incoming-call

I want to create an application that is able to make fake incoming call. Is that possible to use default appearance of Android for that purpose? I know that I can create new appearance but it is not seemed as real incoming call.

Answer (score 1):

Simply if you want to have demo application for call, you can do one thing :

(1) Get **screenshot** of real incoming call screen

(2) Set the **screenshot** as your activity **layout background**

This way starting your activity will show your layout with background as default android incoming call screen

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible to initiate a call (even a fake one) from the device, since if you initiate a call to yourself - than your line becomes busy and you can't receive that call.

you could use [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) which provide call api.

another option, would be to fake the whole scenario. Play the users ring tone, than start the incoming call activity yourself by reflection. That might prove tricky if different manufacturers renamed/moved the activity. You'd end up with a big switch case

Comment: how can I start default incoming call activity?

Comment: Maybe this class would help you get started [PhoneApp.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/phone/PhoneApp.java#PhoneApp)
Specifically, the method [createInCallIntent](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/phone/PhoneApp.java#PhoneApp.createInCallIntent%28%29). You could also call you device, and run `adb shell dumpsys activities` while the incoming call activity is displayed. Then, look for it in the AOSP

Comment: @ guy.gc how can i use this class in my project? please guide me. thank you